# How to connect multiple Azure VMs to log analytics workspace using ARM template?

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template, azure-log-analytics

I can able to connect the Azure VM to the log analytics workspace using the ARM template(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/agents/resource-manager-agent) but I want to connect the multiple VMs at a time in one subscription and different resource groups to the log analytics workspace.
Is there any way to work around this?

Comment: If you want to do that with arm template, I think you can define VM name array then you use `copy` function to deploy. For more details, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/copy-resources?tabs=json

Comment: What does this question have to do with the [`vms`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/vms/info) family of operating systems? You may have tagged it incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a bunch of VMs in a subscription to a log analytics workspace in Azure, we can use PowerShell command `Set-AzVMExtension` to implement it.

For example

```
# all windows VMs in the subscription (which you set via Set-AzContext)
$PublicSettings = @{ "workspaceId" = "" }
$ProtectedSettings = @{ "workspaceKey" = "" }
 
# Using -Status switch to get the status too
Get-AzVM -Status | Where-Object{ $_.Powerstate -eq "VM running" -and $_.StorageProfile.OsDisk.OsType -eq "Windows" } | ForEach-Object { 
    $VMName = $_.Name
    $ResourceGroupName = $_.ResourceGroupName
    $Location = $_.Location
 
    Write-Host "Processing $VMName"
 
    Set-AzVMExtension -ExtensionName "MicrosoftMonitoringAgent" `
    -ResourceGroupName "$ResourceGroupName" `
    -VMName "$VMName" `
    -Publisher "Microsoft.EnterpriseCloud.Monitoring" `
    -ExtensionType "MicrosoftMonitoringAgent" `
    -TypeHandlerVersion 1.0 `
    -Settings $PublicSettings `
    -ProtectedSettings $ProtectedSettings `
    -Location "$Location"
 
}
```

For more details, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/oms-linux?toc=/azure/azure-monitor/toc.json) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/oms-windows?toc=/azure/azure-monitor/toc.json).

Comment: Hi Jim, Many thanks.
I know how to do it in PowerShell but I want to do it through the ARM template. Could you please let me know if you have any idea about this?

Comment: @NARENDER  I think you can define VM name array then you use copy function to deploy. For more details, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/copy-resources?tabs=json